# How to set global CSS in JavaFX 9+ application?

Tags: java, javafx, java-9

There're couple of questions alerady on SO, however since JPMS support none of the answers are valid.

**method 1:** ([JavaFX - Set default CSS stylesheet for the whole Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559981/javafx-set-default-css-stylesheet-for-the-whole-application))

```
Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_MODENA);
StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toString());
```

Doesn't work because `StyleManager` became the part of private API and JavaFX doesn't export it.

**method 2:** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003008/7421700)

```
@import "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css";
/* rest of CSS code */
```

Doesn't work because `modena.css` became the part of private API and JavaFX doesn't export it.

**method 3:** set CSS to the top parent node (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28880421/7421700)

Doesn't work because CSS will not be applied to modal windows.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you only want to _augment_ `modena.css` rather than _replace_ it entirely? Also, regarding method three, is that true even if you set the owner of the window?

Comment: @Slaw yes, I want to complement `modena.css`, just some tweaks. And yes I set modal window owner, and JavaFX doesn't inherit CSS in that case. I suppose it's because `owner != parent`.

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn a window would inherit the CSS of its owner—maybe that only works if the stylesheet is added to the `Scene` of the owner window? Regardless, one option is to use `--add-exports` to grant your code access to `StyleManager`.

Comment: How are you loading the stage and scene in your application? I have no trouble setting a scene I instantiate to the primary stageand adding a style sheet to it which is app wide, including modals. I am using a multi module javafx project, with a custom css loaded from resources

Answer (score 1):

Apply the stylesheet to the scene by calling `Scene`'s `getStylesheets()` method. This is how my application changes the entire application look and feel at runtime:

```java
 private void applyStylesheets(
    final Scene scene, final String internal, final File external ) {
    final var stylesheets = scene.getStylesheets();
    stylesheets.clear();
    stylesheets.add( STYLESHEET_APPLICATION_BASE );
    stylesheets.add( STYLESHEET_MARKDOWN );
    stylesheets.add( getStylesheet( toFilename( internal ) ) );

    try {
      if( external != null && external.canRead() && !external.isDirectory() ) {
        stylesheets.add( external.toURI().toURL().toString() );
        mFileWatchService.register( external );
      }
    } catch( final Exception ex ) {
      clue( ex );
    }
  }
```

The code is doing the following:

1. Obtain a reference to the current stylesheets from the `Scene`.
2. Clear out the list of existing stylesheets.
3. Add the base stylesheet, stylesheet for the rich text editor, then the user-selected stylesheet.
4. Add an externally sourced stylesheet, with additional overrides.
5. Optionally (for you), add a watch on the externally sourced stylesheet so that if the file is changed, the UI is updated immediately.

See the [complete code snippet](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/0f479020921dc4fa9db8084b6d0f15a08a919224/src/main/java/com/keenwrite/MainScene.java#L148) for context and further details.